# CSS image and text aligning

Tags: css, image, text

im having a bit of trouble aligning my images and text how i want them to behave. Im essentually displaying an image with text on the side 3 times in a row. However, I want the first image to be on the left, then the second image to be on the right, and the third and final image to be on the left.

like this:

```
Image   text
text    Image
Image   Text
```

The problem is, when i use float on the middle image, the rest of the content acts like it doesnt exist and gets pushed on top of eachother like this (kind of):

```
Image   Text
Image text text Image
```

I have tried to float ALL the images, but then the text behaves like the images do no exist and gets placed where I do not want it. How would I acheive my desired alignment?

**Edit** Formatting got screwed. Ignore examples lol.

Comment: I think that formatting is ok now? Btw, place each 'line' in one 'row'... That could be solution...

Comment: you can put them in divs, give them proper dimensions and float them.

Comment: ^ ya what he said. Wrap each image and text combo in divs

Comment: Formatting is perfect now, thanks :D. Im trying a lot of the examples right now. Will report back on what worked (Still new to CSS, sorry lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats at the right times. I'm not sure from what you wrote if you want the middle line floated left or right, but something like this should work for you.

```css
#image1 {
  float: left;
}

#text1 {
  float: left;
}

#image2 {
  float: right;
  clear: left;
}

#text2 {
  float: right;
}

#image3 {
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}

#text3 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img alt="Image" id="image1"></img>
<span id="text1">Text</span>

<img alt="Image" id="image2"></img>
<span id="text2">Text</span>

<img alt="Image" id="image3"></img>
<span id="text3">Text</span>
```

Comment: I didn't know I could clear floats. Will definitely read up so i understand it. Thanks for the answer! Its a little ugly, but it worked and I can shorten it (i think lol). Thanks alot!

Comment: Erm guess I cannot shorten it....didnt turn out good combining 1 and 3 (since they are both left). Need to read more about clear i guess.

Answer (score 1):

try out this bin

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/butola/1/edit)

just a crude example

```
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">i am text here</div>
  <img style="width: 50%; float: right;" src="sdlkfj" alt="">

  <img style="width: 50%; float: left;" src="sdlkfj" alt="">
  <div style="width: 50%; float: right;">i am text here</div>

  <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">i am text here</div>
  <img style="width: 50%; float: right;" src="sdlkfj" alt="">
```

Comment: Almost! I actually had something like this too, but they just do not sit how I want them. I guess you have to use "clear" to get rid of the content on the other side of the float. Thanks for the reply and demo though man!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
┌────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ ┌────────────────────┐ │ ┌────────────────────┐ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │       Image        │ │ │        Text        │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ └────────────────────┘ │ └────────────────────┘ │
├────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ ┌────────────────────┐ │ ┌────────────────────┐ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │        Text        │ │ │       Image        │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ └────────────────────┘ │ └────────────────────┘ │
├────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│ ┌────────────────────┐ │ ┌────────────────────┐ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │       Image        │ │ │        Text        │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ │                    │ │ │                    │ │
│ └────────────────────┘ │ └────────────────────┘ │
└────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Where the 2x6 matrix is 6 divs with their own content in it?

Or something like this would work better for you?

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │┌──────────────────────┐┌──────────────────────┐│ │
│ ││                      ││ ┌──────────────────┐ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │      Image       │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││ Text                 ││ └──────────────────┘ ││ │
│ │└──────────────────────┘└──────────────────────┘│ │
│ └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │┌──────────────────────┐┌──────────────────────┐│ │
│ ││ ┌──────────────────┐ ││                      ││ │
│ ││ │                  │ ││                      ││ │
│ ││ │      Image       │ ││                      ││ │
│ ││ │                  │ ││                      ││ │
│ ││ │                  │ ││                      ││ │
│ ││ └──────────────────┘ ││                 Text ││ │
│ │└──────────────────────┘└──────────────────────┘│ │
│ └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │┌──────────────────────┐┌──────────────────────┐│ │
│ ││                      ││ ┌──────────────────┐ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │      Image       │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││                      ││ │                  │ ││ │
│ ││ Text                 ││ └──────────────────┘ ││ │
│ │└──────────────────────┘└──────────────────────┘│ │
│ └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: That was the goal, but it kept buggin out on me and not working how I wanted it to. Ill try it now since im having a slight issue with the correct answer.

Comment: I added a second suggestion, where you have an outer div containing the whole thing, and each "line" is a div containing two divs witch each their content, either an image or text.

Answer (score 0):

How about the working demo below?:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/59fyeeo7/)

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.migman.com/pics/100x100_black.gif"/>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <img src="http://www.migman.com/pics/100x100_black.gif"/>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.migman.com/pics/100x100_black.gif"/>
    <p>Hello World</p>    
</div>
```

css:

```
.content
{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}

.content p
{
    float:left;
}

.content img
{
    float:left;
}
```

I have separated the css and html for convenience and readability.

Comment: Great response man! I like how you have the demo too. I wanted the middle image floating to the right more though (instead of having the text float left, and the the image float left....wanted them both to go right. Minor difference in spacing). Wish I could upvote (still a noob). Thanks though!

Comment: No probs. Glad you found an answer in the end :)